# Facebook Graph - only include status messages posted by page?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set up a Facebook status update feed on a website. However, the current data I am pulling using Facebook's Graph API is including images, likes and so on.

How can I edit this to only include status messages posted by this page onto their own page?

`https://graph.facebook.com/477138555413/feed?access_token=<APP ACCESS TOKEN>`

I tried replacing feed? with statuses? but am being told that 'A user access token is required to request this resource.'

Thanks.

Comment: double check your code and access token, because `PAGE_ID/statuses` should work with any valid access token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a user access token to access the `statuses` connection of a page - if this doesn't work for you for some reason, you need to just request the `feed` connection and filter based on the `to` and `from` values of the posts there.

If this is your page, just use the Page Access Token for the page itself to retrieve the feed. Check the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) documentation for details - when you use the long-lived (60 day) token of the user (from either the Server side Oauth flow or by using the client side flow and extending the token server side) to access the page access token at `/accounts` that page access token will not expire.

Answer (score 0):

All good. I found a simple solution.

I was fetching the data:

```
$FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/477138555413/posts?access_token=<APP ACCESS TOKEN>');
```

Interpreting the data with JSON:

```
$FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);
```

And I was then running a foreach loop to return each status:

```
foreach ($FBdata->data as $news ) {)
```

To filter my results and only show status messages, I added this:

```
if (empty($news->message)) { continue; }
```

All done!

:)